# BrokenPipeError while Running TIMIT example on Kaldi

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, conda, speech-to-text, kaldi

I am trying to install and run the Kaldi TIMIT example.

i.e. `./run.sh` in the `kaldi/egs/timit/s5` directory:

I get the error:

```
fstcompile: error while loading shared libraries: libfstscript.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fstarcsort: error while loading shared libraries: libfstscript.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name=1 mode='w' encoding='latin-1'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am sure I installed Kaldi properly, both copy-feats and hmm-info commands are working well after installing Kaldi.

How could I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check PATH environment variable and disk for the external openfst library, delete it. Make sure you are using openfst commands like fstcompile which you built inside kaldi/tools.